# App close Automatically when Tap on layout

Tags: java, android

I built a tic tac toe app its working fine on my AVD but when i install and open the app on my andriod and Tap on layout(Gridlayout) where i want to play ..app automatically closes. API is 23 both my AVD and my andriod

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Log of app

```
09-29 10:45:10.114 20560-20560/com.example.aquib.tictactoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.aquib.tictactoe, PID: 20560
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method drop(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'imageView8'
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
09-29 10:45:10.132 20560-20560/com.example.aquib.tictactoe E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
```

Comment: @AquibAliKhan please share you xml

Comment: Here is my activity_main.xml https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ttksjkVmbqakpscHJpWTdMV3M/view?usp=sharing